# Difference of timestamps from two columns in seconds to a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am very new to python and have a dataframe as strings in each column

```
df1 = 

         A             B                 C
  0    23:14:25       23:16:34           90
  1    23:14:32       23:19:44           91
```

**I need to generate a new df with difference in timestamps from columns A and B in secs as new column D**

```
df2 = 

         A             B                 C          D
  0    23:14:25       23:16:34           90        (23:16:34-23:14:25)
  1    23:14:32       23:19:44           91        (23:19:44-23:14:32)
```

Is there a way to do these for dataframes directly?

Answer (score 1):

Just create a df with the additional column 'D' that contains the difference in seconds between the times in columns 'A' and 'B'.

```
data = {'A': ['23:14:25', '23:14:32'],
        'B': ['23:16:34', '23:19:44'],
        'C': [90, 91]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

df1['A'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['A'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time
df1['B'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['B'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time

def calculate_diff(row):
    time_a = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), row['A'])
    time_b = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), row['B'])
    return (time_b - time_a).seconds

df1['D'] = df1.apply(calculate_diff, axis=1)

df1
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see a need for apply, simply subtract B from A. Much faster and preferred way of operating with pandas/numpy

Comment: I totally agree with you. Vectorized ops may be advanced for the OP since he mentioned that he is a beginner but I can post an updated answer

Comment: nice. Why opting for an image, though?

Comment: and maybe explain why the use of .combine() and .today() ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pd.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) on both A/B, subtract and get the [`dt.total_seconds`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html):

```
df['D'] = (pd.to_timedelta(df['B'])
           .sub(pd.to_timedelta(df['A']))
           .dt.total_seconds()
          )
```

Alternatively, first converting both columns to seconds, then computing `B-A`:

```
df['D'] = (df[['A', 'B']]
           .apply(lambda s: pd.to_timedelta(s).dt.total_seconds())
           .eval('B-A')
          )
```

Output:

```
          A         B   C      D
0  23:14:25  23:16:34  90  129.0
1  23:14:32  23:19:44  91  312.0
```

Comment: Good use of `.sub` as a precaution, and timedelta is more straightforward than the unnecessary datetime here. Yet doesn't OP need `.seconds` (-->int) rather than `total_seconds()` (--> float) ?

Comment: @OCa no `seconds` would be incorrect, for a timedelta of 1h23min56s this would be `56`. If you want an int just change the dtypes ;)

Comment: `.seconds` does return 129 and 312 though. [Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.seconds.html) say *Timedelta.seconds Return the total hours, minutes, and seconds of the timedelta as seconds. Timedelta.seconds = hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds.* Confused because I don't see the difference between `seconds` and `total_seconds()` except that the later includes time intervals lower than a second. Maybe it is just that.

Comment: Preferred answer, notwithstanding the  `.seconds` vs `.total_seconds()`question. The other answer seems to involve unnecessary calls.

Comment: @OCa yes my bad, this was incorrect `seconds` provides H+M+S, **but would fail if you have days**. For instance `pd.to_timedelta('1day 1:23:45').seconds` -> `5025`. Thus it probably doesn't matter here. I should have double checked before commenting ;)